# Another version of Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: matrices, differential-topology, implicit-function-theorem

So this question is quoted as 'another version of the Implicit Function Theorem, in which we do not specify ahead of time which variables will be implicitly defined ones'. It is also the proof of the 'if' part of a theorem (Manifolds as level sets): $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{M}$ is a $C^k$ m-dimensional manifold if and only if it is locally the pre-image of a regular value of a $C^k$ $\mathbb{R}^{M-m}$-valued function. It's set as an exercise in my lecture notes but because of its importance (to my module) I would really appreciate some feedback.

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{K}^n$ be open, and suppose that $g \in C^1(U;\mathbb{K}^m)$ is such that at $x^* \in U, $dg($x^*$) $\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{K}^n;\mathbb{K}^m)$ is surjective.

(a) QUESTION: Show that there exists indices $i_1,....,i_m \in$ {$1,....m$} such that (Sorry, but I don't know how to insert a matrix) the (square) matrix with entries 
$(\frac{\partial g_a}{\partial x_{i_b}})$ $1 \leq a,b \leq m$ is non singular at $x=x^*$, and indeed for all $x$ in some neighbourhood of $x^*$.

ANSWER: So I basically said since $dg(x^*)$ is surjective, it's rank is $m$ and so there are $m$ linearly independent columns in the corresponding Jacobian Jg$(x^*)$ and so we can use this sub matrix (which is square) and has full rank hence det is non-zero. The result then follows since the det function is continuous.

(b) Show that there is a choice of coordinates $x_1,...,x_n$ on $\mathbb{K}^n$ such that $x_1,...,x_m$ can be written as a well-defined $C^1$ function of $x_{m+1},...,x_{n}$ near $x^*$, and such that the equation $g(x_1,...,x_n) \equiv g(x^*)$ holds.

^ This is the part I'm stuck on, I don't know where to start, I can't do it without using IFT but obviously they don't want us to use that since the question would be pointless.

Comment: In my opinion, I think you are allowed to use IFT here. It might feel like you are "assuming what you're trying to prove", but you are not. You're trying to prove something *similar*, and this is actually pretty common. I'm even more confident in my opinion knowing that the proof of IFT is very difficult - so therefore any equivalent result derived from first principles alone would also be very difficult.

Comment: Also, see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900577/regular-submanifold-in-mathbbr2-is-locally-a-graph/2902256#2902256

Comment: @Prototank hmm yes now you mention it they probably do want me to use IFT since the proof of the IFT takes up 2.5 (non-examinable) pages in my notes and as you said proving something equivalent from first principles is likely to be around same difficulty, thanks for your input anyway because at least now I won't waste any more time trying to prove it lol

Comment: so part (b) is basically just quoting IFT....